# Do I need $R$ being domain to conclude $R\to Frac(R)$ is monic

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

This is the problem 5.58(iii) of Rotman Homological Algebra.

In commutative ring category, $\phi:R\to Frac(R)$ is both monic and epic.

If $R$ is domain, the proof becomes trivial. However, when $NZD(R)\neq \phi$, $Frac(R)=0$. In this case, any morphism $Frac(R)=0\to Y$ requires $1_0\to 1_Y$. So any morphism here is not a ring homomorphism. Is it still epimorphism? This $\phi$ may not be monomorphism as I cannot cancel elements of $R$.

1. When $R$ is not domain, is this still epimorphism? It seems that universal property of localization still works. However, maps mapping out of $Frac(R)$ are no longer ring homomorphism when $Frac(R)=0$.
2. When $R$ is not domain, is this still monomorphism though I cannot cancel elements of $R$ on both sides?

Comment: @user26857 meaning $R$ has non zero divisors.

Comment: Non zero divisors of what?

Comment: A rather pertinent question is, how do you define $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$ and the map $\phi:\ R\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{Frac}(R)$ when $R$ is not a domain? Because you yourself note that no such $\phi$ exists if $R$ has nontrivial zero divisors.

Comment: @Servaes $\phi:r\to \frac{r}{1}$. This map is fine when $R$ is a domain. I can see only maps mapping out of $Frac(R)=0$ are not ring homomorphisms. $\phi$ would still be a ring homomorphism if $R$ has non zero divisors.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Non-zero divisor of $0\in R$.

Comment: How do you define $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$?

Comment: @Servaes Take $R[\{X_r\}]/(rx_r-1)$ where the ideal at the bottom ranges over all $r\in R-{0}$ and $X_r$ is the indeterminates each corresponding to each $r\in R-{0}$.

Comment: I really don't think that's what you want $\operatorname{Frac}{R}$ to be. For $R=\Bbb{Z}$ this makes $\frac{1}{2}\neq\frac{3}{6}$ in $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$.

Comment: @Servaes Call $\frac{1}{2}=x_2, \frac{3}{6}=3x_6$ for $x_6$ corresponds to inverted $6\in Z$. $2(x_2-3x_6)=2x_2-6x_6=1-1=0\in Z[{x_z}]/(zx_z-1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$ when $R$ is a general commutative ring is the localization which inverts only the non-zero divisors of $R$.  So since you only invert non-zero divisors, the canonical map $R\to \operatorname{Frac}(R)$ is always injective.  Indeed, if $\frac{a}{1}=\frac{b}{1}$ in $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$, that means there exists a non-zero divisor $s$ such that $sa=sb$, which implies $a=b$ since $s$ is not a zero divisor.

For it being an epimorphism, *any* localization is an epimorphism.  Indeed, let $R$ be a commutative ring, let $S\subseteq R$ be a multiplicatively closed subset, and let $i:R\to S^{-1}R$ be the canonical map.  Then given a homomorphism $f:S^{-1}R\to T$, $fi(s)$ must be a unit for each $s\in S$, so $f$ must be the unique homomorphism $S^{-1}R\to T$ such that $fi=f\circ i$ given by the universal property of $i$.  In particular, the uniqueness says that if $fi=gi$, then $f=g$, so $i$ is epic.

(Incidentally, the possiblity that the localization $S^{-1}R$ might be the zero ring is completely irrelevant to this argument.  If there exist no homomorphisms $S^{-1}R\to T$ for some ring $T$, then the condition that $i$ is epic simply becomes vacuous.  In any case, even if $S^{-1}R$ is the zero ring, that doesn't mean there are *no* homomorphisms out of it, since it can still map to the zero ring.)